# Autofac MVC 5 RegisterWebApiFilterProvider causes unresolveable IOverrideFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a simple MVC app in which I'm trying to add an exception filter. To do that, I followed the [Autofac WebAPI Integration documentation](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Web-Api-Integration) that I believe applies to the Autofac.WebApi2 NuGet package.

First, I **created the exception filter**:

```
public class ErrorLoggingExceptionFilter : IAutofacExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

I then **added the AutofacControllerConfiguration attribute** to my API controller base class that I want the exception filter applied to:

```
[AutofacControllerConfiguration]
public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController  {}
```

Then I **registered the exception filter** with Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<ErrorLoggingExceptionFilter>()
    .AsWebApiExceptionFilterFor<ApiControllerBase>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

At this point the application still runs fine, but the exception filter doesn't run, so I then **registered autofac's filter provider**:

```
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

As soon as that's added I start getting 500's with the following error:

> `None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Autofac.Features.Metadata.Meta1[System.Web.Http.Filters.IOverrideFilter]' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.Http.Filters.IOverrideFilter value' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.Http.Filters.IOverrideFilter, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary2[System.String,System.Object])'`.

I'm not using any metadata in this project nor do I know anything about `IOverrideFilter`.

What am I missing that's preventing my exception filter from working?

**UPDATE & Response to Comments**

The project is using ASP.NET MVC 5.1, using the following Autofac and WebApi NuGet versions:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I see the same result with Autofac 3.3.

It turns out I can reproduce it by calling only the `RegisterWebApiFilterProvider` method, so although I put together a complete sample I didn't bother including the above exception filter. The sample project that can be used to reproduce it is available on my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2W7AjD-qci-UFVRTVlTTjRZSFU/edit?usp=sharing).

For reference, here's the full stack trace:

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Autofac.Features.Metadata.Meta`1[System.Web.Http.Filters.IOverrideFilter]' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.Http.Filters.IOverrideFilter value' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.Http.Filters.IOverrideFilter, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object])'.
at
Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RegistrationsFor>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) at
Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.ResolveControllerScopedOverrideFilter(FilterContext filterContext, String metadataKey) at
Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() at
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at
System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() at
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1.MoveNext() at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.<RemoveDuplicates>d__3.MoveNext() at
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1.MoveNext() at
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.InitializeFilterPipeline() at
System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at
System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline() at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterGrouping() at
System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I am not able to repro this exception with the code from you post. Please add your web.api and autofac package version! Also and full exception stacktace would be helpful to identify the problem... You should also try to repro this yourself in a new MVC5 app and extend your post with the missing part for the repro.

Comment: @nemesv - I've linked to a complete minimized test case and updated my post to answer your questions. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It is the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` which causing this problem if you remove the line `builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());` then your code is working fine...

Comment: But I would say that this is a bug in Autofac because if you register at least one override filter with `builder.OverrideWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>();` then it is working also with `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource`...

Comment: @nemesv - That does indeed "Fix" the error. I think "it's a bug" and "here's a workaround" is a very legitimate answer to the question. Feel free to make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that this is [bug?](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/495) or at least an unexpected interference between two Autofac features.

So this is what is happening:

- Because you are using the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` in your sample Autofac tries to register and resolve every type which is not derictly registered in the controller
- When calling `builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` Autofac tries to localate all the filter and amongs them the registered IOverrideFilters with calling `Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<IOverrideFilter>>>`
- However if no `IOverrideFilter` registered then Autofac treats `Meta<IOverrideFilter>` as unresolvable so the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` kickc in which tries to instantiate a `Meta<IOverrideFilter>` and throws the exception.

There are multiple workaround for this problem:

- Just don't use the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` altough this is probably not what you want to do.
- Register at least one filter override

  ```
   builder.OverrideWebApiActionFilterFor<SomeController>();
  ```

  so the container will contain a `Meta<IOverrideFilter>` so the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` won't run for this type. Again if you don't have filters to override this is not a good solution.
- You can tell the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` which types should it resolve so you can also tell that it should not resolve  `Meta<T>`:

  ```
  builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource(
   t => !(t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Meta<>))));
  ```